# A function $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \ \mathbb{Z}$ is defined by $f(n)$ = $2n+1$. Determine whether $f$ is injective and surjective.

Tags: proof-explanation, solution-verification

$f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \ \mathbb{Z}$  is defined by $f(n)$ = $2n+1$

I proved injective first:

$f(a) = f(b)$ therefore it is $a = b$

$2a + 1$ = $2b+1$

$2a = 2b$

a = b , therefore $f(n) = 2n+1$ is injective

now for surjective, I proved this by

Let $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ so there exist $ n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(n) = r$

$2n+1 = r$ , $n = \frac{r-1}{2}$ , $f(\frac{r-1}{2}) = 2(\frac{r-1}{2}) + 1$ and that equals $r$. Therefore it is surjective.

I looked the answer is says: the function is injective but there is no surjective because there is no $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(2) = 2$. I am trying to figure out, why I am wrong?

Comment: $\frac{r-1}{2}$ is not always an integer.

Comment: Can you get an even number as the function value?

Answer (score 3):

For $r=2, {{2-1}\over 2}$ is not an element of $\mathbb{Z}$,

$g:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ defined by $g(n)=2n+1$ is surjective, but its restriction on $\mathbb{Z}$ is not surjective, since the image of every element of $\mathbb{Z}$ is odd.

Comment: is the image is odd for the rationals? 

so my r isn't in integers  that's why it isn't surjective?

Comment: not necessarily, $g({1\over 2})=2$. but ${1\over 2}$ is not an integer.

Comment: so therefore it isn't surjective due to the fraction because the fraction isn't in the integer set and image of function's output 

":ℚ→ℚ defined by ()=2+1 is surjective, but its restriction on ℤ is not surjective, since the image of every element of ℤ is odd." for this is surjective for rationals but not for integers that are only odds to the function outputs, right? 

if so I misjudgment my answer, should of knew the outputs of the function is odd, and domain will not be onto with the image.

Answer (score 1):

Range of your function is $\pm$ odd numbers, so you cannot obtain even one.

$$2m=2n+1 \Rightarrow n=\frac{2m-1}{2} \notin \mathbb{Z}$$